# How to correctly use external code in commercial ISV apps

Tags: licenses, isv, libraries, open-source

The open-source ecosystem around Salesforce.com is getting bigger every day and smart ISVs don't reinvent every wheel needed for their app.

How can app developer stay safe when using libraries like [FinancialForce Apex Commons](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-common/blob/master/LICENSE) or the [Lightning components of Appiphony Strike](https://github.com/appiphony/Strike-Components/blob/master/LICENSE.txt) .

How and especially *where in the app* can providers of managed (binary) packages fulfill license requirements like:

> Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
>   notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
>   documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.

Comment: what is the difference between first and second requirement?

Comment: Perhaps you can provide a release note with your application with a section devoted to 3rd party licensing.

Comment: @PhilHawthorn can you point me to any example app that uses this method?